# Rails 4: Advanced Rest API Approach and Examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, restful-architecture

I'm creating a restful API for my app in Rails 4. I took a look at so many tutorials on that theme but in general they are all limited to creating a CRUD (create read update delete) API. That's easy and I already did that. But now i need to implement custom API endpoints behind which I perform various data processing.
How can I do that in a right way?
Where can I find information on the approach to building beautiful and relatively complex restful apis (like Foursquare API) in Ruby on Rails? Maybe there are real life open source examples?

Comment: You may be jumping to custom endpoints too quickly. Think about your data model from the perspective of resources. Are you sure you can't handle some of this data processing with general CRUD actions?

Comment: clexmond, it seems like with only CRUD actions I will need to make some calculations on the iOS client which is no good I suppose. Besides I want to get some general knowledge in designing APIs.

Comment: For instance I need to calculate average number of participants in the table named events. Do I need to add a GET 'average' method to events_controller, or maybe I am missing a point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful way of thinking about a RESTful API architecture is to think in terms of "nouns rather than verbs". REST is all about resources and resources should be nouns (e.g. a user or an event) rather than verbs (e.g. calculate or process).

To apply that to your problem of calculating the average number of participants in your events table, we have to think about what *noun* would represent that as a resource. It sounds like what you are getting at is some sort of *report*. This report would contain statistics such as the average number of participants as well as any other statistics that you might want to calculate down the road.

Your route might look something like this:

```
# singular resource
resource :events_report, only: [:show]
```

This will result in the following endpoint: `/events_report` which could return an `EventsReport` resource containing the result of all the processing you might want to do. This resource could be calculated on-the-fly (i.e. in the controller) or it could be pre-processed and stored in an ActiveRecord model.

The key to a good architecture is to not think of your endpoints as verbs (e.g. average) but as nouns (e.g. report) instead.

A good resource to check out would be the [*Art of Rails*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470189487) book, specifically Chapter 6. - Resources and REST.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. Will it be "RESTish" to for example put the `average` method in the EventsController and use it as `/events/average_number_of_participants`? Special thanks for the book,  it seems to cover my questions.

Comment: IMO `/events/average_number_of_participants` is still a bit action-oriented and narrowly-focused. In that case you aren't really returning a resource per-say, but rather a single bit of data. If that bit of data was included in a `Report` resource, that seems a bit more RESTish to me.

That being said, there's nothing that says you 100% shouldn't do it that way if it makes the most sense for your app.

Comment: Carlos, I think now I get your point. It still seems to me that having a separate resource Report with corresponding controller for just one 'average' calculation is a bit odd, but I understood that in terms of REST it will be more correct. And now I know how to continue API designing, thanks a lot again.

Comment: I definitely see what you're saying-- having a whole other resource just for a single calculation may seem like overkill. But what if you end up wanting to add some other calculations? Rather than having to add new endpoints for each one, you can just include them in your `Report` resource and still maintain the same single endpoint. Good luck and I'm glad I could help!